# how to resolve the warning warning C4251: .... needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'TestClass'

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, dllexport

I create below simple class and build it

```
class __declspec(dllexport) TestClass
{
private:
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex > lock;
public:
    void doIt() {
        // do something
    }
};
```

but I met the below warning

1>C:\gitview\frm_multi\framework\appCpp\acout.h(48,35): warning C4251: 'TestClass::lock': class 'std::unique_lockstd::mutex' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'TestClass'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\mutex(593): message : see declaration of 'std::unique_lockstd::mutex'

after I googled some article, I updated my code like below

```
template<> class __declspec(dllexport) std::unique_lock<std::mutex>;

class __declspec(dllexport) TestClass
{
private:
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex > lock;
public:
    void doIt() {
        // do something
    }
};
```

at this moment, I met below error...

1>C:\gitview\frm_multi\framework\appCpp\acout.h(45,9): error C2908: explicit specialization; 'std::unique_lockstd::mutex' has already been instantiated

how to solve this situation?
what I first try is just to expose my class outside DLL.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of your warning like this:

```
using PrivateData = struct {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex > lock;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) TestClass {
private:
  PrivateData data;
public:
  void doIt() {
    // do something
  }
};
```

If users of your component don't need to know about private members, you can consider to expose only an interface :

```
class __declspec(dllexport) TestClass {
  virtual void doIt() = 0;
};

class TestClassImplementation: public TestClass {
private:
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock;
public:
  void doIt() {
    // do something
  }
};
```

Comment: ok got it. but I'm not sure that this kind of wrapping(?) approach is standard one. it looks tricky way...